# MySQL - count() for any row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an erd like this:

[erd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbABh.png)

and I want all Actors working-number with one specific director.
this is my query:

```
    SELECT 
    p.first_name, p.last_name, COUNT(r.movie_id) as working_number
FROM
    person p
          LEFT JOIN
    roles r ON r.person_id = p.id
WHERE
    r.movie_id IN (SELECT 
            r.movie_id
        FROM
            roles r
        WHERE
            role_type = 'Director'
                AND person_id = (SELECT 
                    id
                FROM
                    person
                WHERE
                    first_name = 'Quentin'
                        AND last_name = 'Tarantino'))
                        and r.role_Type = "Actor"
GROUP BY p.id;
```

this retrieves actors who with the working-number more than 1.
I want other actors too, even with 0 working-number.

Comment: Query can be valid when [Functional Dependency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) can be used meaning atleast MySQl 5.7.5+ with enabled sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.. **Do not trust Functional Dependency under MySQL 5.7.5 or disabled sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY**, otherwise this query is just plain and simple [invalid](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need multiple left joins, twice for `person` and `role`:

```
SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, COUNT(pd.id) as working_number
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN role r ON r.person_id = p.id AND r.role_Type = 'Actor'
LEFT JOIN role rd ON rd.movie_id = r.movie_id AND rd.role_type = 'Director'
LEFT JOIN person pd ON pd.id = rd.person_id AND pd.first_name = 'Quentin' AND pd.last_name = 'Tarantino'
GROUP BY p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name
```

Comment: Looks good to me. But if you only want actors, the first JOIN should be an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel From the question: *I want other actors too, even with 0 working-number* so what if there are actors without any roles? This is why I use only LEFT joins.

Comment: I see what you mean. OP didn't clearly define what an "actor" is. I thought an actor had at least one role (as actor) in a movie.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use left join table columns  in where  clause  .. in this way the join work as an INNER JOIN
try add these condition to the LEFT JOIN ON clause

```
SELECT p.first_name
     , p.last_name
     , COUNT(r.movie_id) as working_number
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN roles r ON r.person_id = p.id 
  AND r.movie_id IN (
    SELECT r.movie_id
    FROM roles r
    WHERE role_type = 'Director'
    AND person_id = ( 
      SELECT id
      FROM person
      WHERE first_name = 'Quentin'
      AND last_name = 'Tarantino')
  )
  and r.role_Type = "Actor"
GROUP BY p.first_name, p.last_name;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that [Functional Dependency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) only can be trusted to be used from MySQL 5.7.5+ and with a enabled sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY..